# Same array/msgbox to display different messages

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, collections, msgbox

Currently my array brings up three different msgboxes, as shown with the Functions 'Expired', 'Expiring', and 'NoTraining'. The array msgboxes display information based on whether a date is Expired (older than current date), Expiring (within 31 days), and is a date is missing (NoTraining). No matter what, these msgboxes for the array will always come up, but will sometimes be blank (depending on the criteria in the SELECT CASE statement). Does anyone know anyway of coding it so that if the msgboxes were to come up blank (if nothing fits the criteria), a different message will be shown in the box? I can't get the collection and boolean NoExpiredTraining to work properly bringing up an overall msgbox instead of the array msgboxes, so I am unsure what to do.

This is my code:

```
    Sub Expire_New()

Dim arr()       As Variant
Dim msg(1 To 3) As String
Dim x           As Long
Dim nDx         As Long
Dim dDiff       As Long
LDays = 31

'I would recommend using a named sheet rather than
'ActiveSheet as this can change unexpectedly
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Support Staff")
With ws
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TRAINING_DATE_COL).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Cells(21, 1).Resize(x - 20, 26).Value
End With

'I am a big fan of collections.  They make code easier to read
'and to implement.  The collection below will be scanned to
'see if there are any training dates that are set to expire within
'30 days or if there are people without any training
Dim colTrainingDate As Collection
Set colTrainingDate = CopyArrDimToCollection(arr, TRAINING_DATE_COL)

'This boolean will be used to control continued flow of the
'macro.  If NoExpiredTraining gets set to false, then there
'are people who must complete training.
'Dim NoExpiredTraining As Boolean: NoExpiredTraining = True

For x = LBound(arr, NAME_COL) To UBound(arr, NAME_COL)

    'Since every row requires a Name and Surname columns
    'to have data in them, let's check this first.
    'If a row doesn't have a name then skip it.
    If arr(x, NAME_COL) <> "" And arr(x, SURNAME_COL) <> "" Then

        'Always good practice to declare your variables/objects
        'relevant to where they will be used
        'vDx is an index used to loop through the collection of
        'Training Dates.  This is checking to see if any training
        'Dates are empty or less than 31 days from expiration
        Dim vDx As Variant
        For Each vDx In colTrainingDate
            If vDx = "" Then
                'blank date means needs training
                NoExpiredTraining = False
            ElseIf DateDiff("d", Date, vDx) < 31 Then
                'less than 31 days means needs training
                NoExpiredTraining = False
            End If
        Next

        'At this point you can determine if you want to continue
        'If there is no expired training, display the message and exit
        'the sub.
        If NoExpiredTraining Then
            'msg(4) = MsgBox("There are either no ...
            'is only used if want to do something based on
            'what button the user pressed.  Otherwise use
            'the Method form of MsgBox
            MsgBox "There are either no expired safeguarding certificates, or no certificate expiring within the next 31 days.", vbCritical, "Warning"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'There is expired training.  Let's collect the status
            'of each individual
            If arr(x, TRAINING_DATE_COL) = "" Then
                'if the training date column is empty
                'put a really big default value in dDiff
                'otherwise you have to trap an error with DateDiff
                'and handle it
                dDiff = 100
            Else
                'training date column has a date value
                dDiff = DateDiff("d", Date, arr(x, TRAINING_DATE_COL))
            End If

            'Now let's see what the training status for the person is
            Select Case dDiff
                Case Is <= 0:   'Training is expired
                    msg(1) = Expired(msg(1), _
                          arr(x, NAME_COL), _
                          arr(x, 2), _
                          arr(x, TRAINING_DATE_COL))
                Case Is <= 31:  'Training is expiring
                    msg(2) = Expiring(msg(2), _
                          arr(x, NAME_COL), _
                          arr(x, 2), _
                          arr(x, TRAINING_DATE_COL), dDiff)
            End Select
            If Len(arr(x, 19)) = 0 And Len(arr(x, 1)) > 0 And Len(arr(x, 2)) > 0 Then
         msg(3) = NoTraining(msg(3), arr(x, 1), arr(x, 2), arr(x, 18))

  End If
  End If
  End If


 Next x
'Because of the Exit Sub statement above, the code bwlow
'will only execute if there are expired, expiring or missing
'training
For x = LBound(msg) To UBound(msg)
    msg(x) = Replace(msg(x), "@NL", vbCrLf)
    If Len(msg(x)) < 1024 Then
        MsgBox msg(x), vbExclamation, "Safeguarding Certificate Notification"
    Else
       MsgBox "String length for notification too long to fit into this MessageBox", vbExclamation, "Invalid String Length to Display"
    End If
Next x




Erase arr
Erase msg

End Sub

'***************************************************************************
'**
'** This fucntion copies all rows of data for the column specified into
'** a collection
Private Function CopyArrDimToCollection(ByRef mMultiDimArray() As Variant, _
                                    ByVal mColumnToCopy As Long) As Collection
Dim retVal As New Collection
Dim nDx As Long

For nDx = LBound(mMultiDimArray, 1) To UBound(mMultiDimArray, 1)
    retVal.Add mMultiDimArray(nDx, mColumnToCopy)
Next
Set CopyArrDimToCollection = retVal

End Function

Private Function Expired(ByRef msg As String, ByRef var1 As Variant, ByRef 
var2 As Variant, ByRef var3 As Variant) As String

If Len(msg) = 0 Then msg = "Persons with EXPIRED Safeguading 
Certificates@NL@NL"

Expired = msg & "(@var3) @var1 @var2@NL"
Expired = Replace(Expired, "@var1", var1)
Expired = Replace(Expired, "@var2", var2)
Expired = Replace(Expired, "@var3", var3)


End Function

Private Function Expiring(ByRef msg As String, ByRef var1 As Variant, ByRef 
var2 As Variant, ByRef var3 As Variant, ByRef d As Long) As String

If Len(msg) = 0 Then msg = "Persons with EXPIRING Safeguarding 
Certificates@NL@NL"

Expiring = msg & "(@var3) @var1 @var2 (@d days remaining)@NL"
Expiring = Replace(Expiring, "@var1", var1)
Expiring = Replace(Expiring, "@var2", var2)
Expiring = Replace(Expiring, "@var3", var3)
Expiring = Replace(Expiring, "@d", d)

End Function

Private Function NoTraining(ByRef msg As String, ByRef var1 As Variant, 
ByRef 
var2 As Variant, ByRef var3 As Variant) As String

If Len(msg) = 0 Then msg = "SAFEGUARDING TRAINING NOT COMPLETED FOR @NL@NL"

NoTraining = msg & " @var1 @var2@NL"
NoTraining = Replace(NoTraining, "@var1", var1)
NoTraining = Replace(NoTraining, "@var2", var2)
NoTraining = Replace(NoTraining, "@var3", var3)

End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried a `case...else` statement?

Comment: @oxwilder Sadly, a CASE ELSE will come up for anything that isn't EXPIRED, EXPIRING, or NoTraining. Which means that anything that is one of the above will still come up. I need either just one box to come up, or a message in the array to say that everything is fine.

Comment: Is there anyway to do a CASE ELSE, that will cancel the other options and only display one message rather than displaying it for every single bit of data that matches the Else statement?

Comment: Sorry, still early for me to wrap my head around this :) Could you add an `if` statement to your `case else` that evaluates the contents of `TRAINING_DATE_COL`?

Comment: @oxwilder I have tried yes, but this still comes up with a message for every line where there is nothing that is expired, expiring, or missing. I would need it to just come up once!

Comment: I feel like there must be a way of doing from within the three private functions. The function will be called no matter what, and currently they will either come back blank, or there will be the data that the CASE ELSE selected

Comment: Does `NoExpiredTraining` come up as false or nothing in the case of an empty/blank vDx?

Comment: NoExpiredTraining doesn't come up at all - this is the one that should come up and stop the rest of the array and SELECT CASE statement. Sadly I don't think I can word it correctly. The vdx searches 19 (TRAINING_DATE_COL) for any blanks and sets NoExpiredTraining to false. It then searches for if the date in column 19 is less than 31 days away, and if it is, it sets it to off. I need it to turn it to TRUE, if there are no blanks, and if the date is larger than 31 days away. Does that make sense?!?

Comment: I saw you had the `NoExpiredTraining` dim commented out. What was the behavior before commenting it out? I'm basically looking for the result of `If NoExpiredTraining Then` because it will either come up as true, false, or nothing, right?

Comment: @oxwilder It was an accident to comment it out, but even after removing the ' it still does nothing. I feel like there must be another IF statement to get it to set to true after all the collection sorting, where then the msgbox will appear. I have tried all sorts of different things, but just can't work it out.

Comment: I have tried                                                                                                                 
    If Len(arr(x, 19)) > 0 And Len(arr(x, 1)) > 0 And Len(arr(x, 2)) > 0 And DateDiff("d", Date, vDx) > 31 Then
        NoExpiredTraining = True
        If NoExpiredTraining Then
            MsgBox "There are either no expired safeguarding certificates, or no certificate expiring within the next 31 days.", vbCritical, "Warning"
            
            Exit Sub                                                                                           
       Else

Comment: Try `Select Case True` construction, then you can create more cases with conditions containing arbitrary variables.

Comment: @omegastripes Have tried, but it doesn't seem to work. Everything comes up blank.